# C# read next line from clipboard and wrap line in quotes?

Tags: c#

I have a program I am writing similar to find and replace. I am working in SQL and on a daily basis I copy a result of data and need to do a search on a 100 more accounts. I have managed to add them into the clipboard and manipulate the clipboard to wrap in quotes. However I am wondering is it possible to read lines in a clipboard? The general output will be as below

This is the Current output 
"123456
123456
123456
123456
123456
123456"

Output should be 
"123456",
"123456",
"123456",
"123456",
"123456",
"123456"

The code I have so far is below it is a winform application

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ARMGUID
{
    public sealed class HotkeyWindow : NativeWindow, IDisposable
    {
        public HotkeyWindow()
        {
            CreateHandle(new CreateParams());
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
            if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
            {
                string ARMguid = Clipboard.GetText();
                string s = "\"" + ARMguid+"\n" + "\"";


                Clipboard.SetText(s);

            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            DestroyHandle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I heard it works if you move your engine to where it should be from the middle of the car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try splitting, wrapping and joining back:

```
  string result = string.Join("," + Environment.NewLine, Clipboard
    .GetText()
    .Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(line => "\"" + line + "\""));

  Clipboard.SetText(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string ARMguid = Clipboard.GetText();
    string[] lines = ARMguid.Split('\n');
    foreach(var line in lines)
        result += "\"" + ARMguid + "\",\n";

    Clipboard.SetText(result);
}
```